# Does Microsoft Edge update Chrome Extensions automatically?

Tags: google-chrome-extensions, microsoft-edge, chrome-web-store

I've now installed some Chrome Extensions from the Chrome Web Store in Microsoft Edge. Will these addons update automatically?

Comment: It looks to work the same as Chrome - if you turn on *Extensions* > *Developer Options* there is an "Update" option.   Whether it also does it automatically like Chrome idk but presumably.

Comment: Are you talking about the Microsoft Edge that comes bundled with Windows or Microsoft Edge Dev which is based on the Chromium browser?

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder It's the new version of Microsoft Edge that is based on Chromium just like Google Chrome. More info is available here: https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/.

Comment: @WilliamV - Chromium based Edge was released on Jan 15 for macOS and Windows.  Windows users will get it eventually through Windows Update or it can be downloaded now (for any OS) from [microsoft.com/edge](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/edge).  See the blog [Upgrading to the new Microsoft Edge](https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2020/01/15/upgrading-new-microsoft-edge-79-chromium/)
 Chrome Web Store extensions will not work on legacy Edge.

Comment: @WilliamV. I think it's just called "Microsoft Edge" and not "Microsoft Edge Dev".

Comment: @MikaelDúiBolinder Ok, thank you I may have been mistaken.